# Problems with libraries in JMonkey

Tags: java, class, libraries, jmonkeyengine

Started using jMonkeyEngine SDK for the first time this week and I have kind of been thrown in at the deep end. I have inherited somebody else’s code and I am struggling to get it running on their machine (they are also on holiday for a few weeks so out of contact).

The problem is when I attempt to run the code I get errors like :

> WARNING: class [jme3test.helloworld.StartScreen] could not be instantiated (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jme3test.helloworld.StartScreen)

I was under the impression that these would fix themselves after importing the `jme3-test-data.jar` but it has not.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or what libraries I need?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you using Jmonkey within it's own IDE (based on netbeans) or are you using it as a library within annother IDE

Comment: Could we see how you're using jme3test.helloworld.StartScreen

Answer (score 4):

Within this answer I am assuming you are using the standard JMonkey IDE

When using a jar you also need to add it to your project as well as adding the applicable import.

You do this as follows

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, I'm not familiar with jme3test.helloworld.StartScreen being part of that library. It may be part of annother jar. If so you will need to use the "add  Jar/Folder" button and find the Jar with `jme3test.helloworld.StartScreen` in it